# How change require to import with key in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to write require with ES6 import. In the case without a key, it is pretty easy to do:

`var args2 = require('yargs2');` -> `import foo from 'bar';`

But with a key, I can't find the appropriate syntax:

```
var foo = require('bar').key;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: why does the first case work? It should not work in general. The names of things matter and you need to know them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The syntax for importing a member of a module with an aliased name is:

```
import {key as foo} from 'bar';
```

This is equivalent to `var foo = require('bar').key;`

If you want to import a member without aliasing it, the syntax is simpler:

```
import {foo} from 'bar';
```

Is equivalent to:

```
 var foo = require('bar').foo;
```

[MDN article about the import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: `import {xxx}` requires a named export (`export xxx`). OP uses default import ([*ImportedDefaultBinding*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports)) in `import foo from 'bar'` so this won't work. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`var foo = require('bar').key` is identical to `var bar = require('bar'); var foo = bar.key` (other then the declaration of a 'bar' variable that is probably no longer needed).

if you export an object that has a property named 'key', that would be the same in ES6 import/export.

```
import bar from 'bar';
var foo = bar.key;
```

***Note*** This assumes a default export (`export default xxx`) as in OP. If using a named export (`export foo`), the syntax to use is `import {foo} from 'bar'`